# Is there control I can add to a windows form that is similar to the Properties window in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio

I want to add something similar to the the properties window in Visual Studio into my form application.  Basically a grid that has a label in the first column and a editable value in the second column.  I can't seem to find something like it.  Any examples of what to use and/how how to use it would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The control you are looking for is the [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx).

I recommend reading [Getting the Most Out of the .NET Framework PropertyGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx) for details on how to work with this control fully, including customizing it for your types.